# PDO, sqlite3 и внешний ключ

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite3

Я создал две таблицы. Первая со списком статей, а вторая с категориями. Вот они:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `title` TEXT,
    `date`  INTEGER,
    `text`  TEXT,
    `category`  INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `category`  TEXT
);
```

Необходимо следующее: при выводе статей, нужно, кроме id категории получать ещё и название категории из таблицы с категориями.

Также, нужно выводить все статьи из определённой категории по её id.

Искал в сети, но информации как мне показалось весьма мало. Я даже не знаю как сформулировать запрос, не говоря уже о выводе PDO. Помогите, люди добрые!

P. S. Я создавал ещё внешний ключ FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES categories(id), но он «испарился», видимо не сохранился при закрытии программы :)

Comment: не надо искать специально для sqlite. в примитивных запросах синтаксис совпадает для всех диалектов sql и, в частности, с mysql. А для неё информации в интернете вагон и маленькая тележка.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Скажите, а правильно я составил внешний ключ исходя из моих потребностей FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES categories(id)?

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего представления, я никогда не работал с sqlite. я могу только сказать что никакой внешний ключ здесь не нужен.

Comment: А как же связать таблицы? Просто в запросе?

Comment: Да, просто в запросе. Посмотрите на вопрос, который вам предложили в качестве дубликата: там есть и синтаксис sql, который вам нужен (хотя я бы написал через INNER JOIN) и пример кода PHP. Проголосовал за "Оставить закрытым" - пока не вижу причин для переоткрытия.

Comment: Честно говоря, я не понимаю вообще как реализовать мои задачи. Вроде всё прочитал на несколько раз, всё равно не пойму.

Comment: Если внимательно прочитали у вас должно было получиться что то вроде `select a.*, c.category as category_name from articles a join categories on c.id=a.category` оно даст все статьи с названиями категории. Для выбора по конкретной категории достаточно добавить `where a.category=?` и передать id соответствующей категории при execute

Comment: Примерно ясно, но выдаёт ошибку: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: c.category' in /site.org/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /site.org/index.php(21): PDO->query('SELECT a.*, c.c...') #1 {main} thrown in /site.org/index.php on line 21 Вроде бы говорит, что отсутствует столбец c.category?